# Creating a List of Objects throwing compiler error

Tags: java, arrays, list, object, generics

I am currently studying generics as part of my programming class, and I'm having problems understanding why the following code throws a compiler error:

```
List<Object> objs = Arrays.asList(1,"2");
```

From what I'm aware, if you do not explicitly declare the type parameter for the method, for example `Arrays.<Integer>asList();` then it is generated for you, using the most reasonable choice.

The following code:

```
List<Object> objs = Arrays.<Object>asList(1,"2");
```

works because i'm explicitly telling the compiler, "I want this method's type parameter to be Object", but I am curious why this is not done successfully automatically?

Comment: Do you compilation error for "List<Object> objs = Arrays.asList(1,"2");"? I just tried it and I didn't get any compilation error.

Comment: It works for Java 8 :)

Comment: `<? extends Object> List<? extends Object> java.util.Arrays.asList(? extends Object... arg0)`

Comment: What Java version are you using? Type inference is slowly getting better and your example compiles fine with Java8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue appears because different type arguments were passed to a method Arrays.asList, so the compiler tried to find the intersection of all super types of your type arguments.

You created a list with `String` and `int` parameters. So compiler found only Serializable as common interface.

This will be compiled:

```
List<? extends Serializable> list = Arrays.asList(1, "2");
```

Reference to read:
http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ404

Answer (score 2):

`List<Object> objs = Arrays.asList(1, "2")` will only work with Java 8 :)

Even `List<Object> objs = Arrays.asList("a", "b")` will compile with Java 8.

Check these references:

- [JEP 101: Generalized Target-Type Inference](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101)
- [A Lesser-Known Java 8 Feature: Generalized Target-Type Inference](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/11/25/a-lesser-known-java-8-feature-generalized-target-type-inference/)